# Word in English that illustrate the meaning of humor and criticism

Tags: synonyms

Is there a combined word in English that illustrate the meaning of **humor** and **criticism**?

For example, I want to say that I watch TV programs, which criticize wrongdoings of politicians in a humorous way. Is there any word that can substitute **criticize** avoiding the need to write **in a humorous way** because it completes the meaning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd go with **[Political Satire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_satire)**.

Satire can be serious in intent, but is usually without a specific agenda, merely lampooning politicians & current affairs for comedic effect.

Answer (score 0):

The commonest is: ***sarcasm***. The other phrases include ***tongue in cheek*** and ***satire.*** They may all be used depending on the context. But largely, you can tell things in a *sarcastic way* to sound serious, funny, and equally with irony.

In your context, you like to watch TV series with *sarcasm* on politics. If there is a specific dialogue you can certainly call as a [tongue in cheek](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tongue-in-cheek) remark that would show both -irony and humor. You can also have [*sarcastic*](https://www.imdb.com/list/ls000076245/) TV series.

Comment: I will be very glad if you will help me correct my mistakes in the question, I asked. 
I am also baffled by the use of which or who after comma

Comment: @Charlie then you should post a new question about the use of which or who, but do a search to check whether it has already been asked...

Comment: I found an answer at  https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/130155/44846. I guess I must use which because that is more common.

Comment: I'd use *that* @Charlie I watch the programs *that* sarcastically present politics or whatever.

Comment: "Pun", "sarcasm" and "satire" can all be used to describe types of humour, but they're quite different.

Comment: @psmears true and I've mentioned that if you have missed it in the answer. *depends on the context.* You can have *pun, tongue in cheek comment, and sarcasm* in political satire. Who says no?

Comment: @MaulikV: I saw that, but since you also say "they all mean almost the same" just before, I think the answer is misleading. You *can* have puns and tonguie in cheek comments in political satire, but they're quite different forms of humour.

Comment: Say there's a dialogue spoken by a politician's wife in a political satire: *Yeah, of course, you can promise many things and don't bother about fulfilling 'emll!* Now, this is satire, pun, tongue in cheek comment and everything you can think of. @psmears

Comment: I'm not seeing the pun there, but I'll take your word for it... so OK, what does that imply? A car can be a vehicle, red, metallic and heavy, all at the same time - but it doesn't mean that all of those words mean the same thing! :)

Comment: I don’t think sarcasm, satire, pun, and tongue-in-cheek mean the same thing at all.  This has examples of puns: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/164695/ They are just a form of word play joke, and don’t have anything to do with criticism. Sarcasm is more often just plain mean criticism than actually funny, like the examples in these answers https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/44733/9161 Satire is really the only one of those words that implies both humor and criticism.

Comment: @ColleenV *Satire is the only one of those...*? Nope! The *tongue in cheek* also means the same. Link added and answer edited. Yes, *pun* wasn't an accurate choice so removed.